# Style of django admin is not shown

Tags: django, docker, nginx, django-admin, django-staticfiles

This is how my Django admin page looks like:

[image]

Though in my network section this is the result:
[image]

And the url path of these requests are correctly set by the static url, these are the Django settings:

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
```

I collect statics before serving my app:
 `RUN python3 manage.py collectstatic --noinput` (This is part of my Dockerfile)

some parts of my docker-compose:

```
  web:
    restart: always
    image: <some private image>
    ports:
      - "127.0.0.1:8000:8000"
    volumes:
      - static_volume:/<path>/static

  nginx:
    container_name: nginx
    image: nginx:1.19.3
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 80:80
      - 443:443
    volumes:
      - static_volume:/home/status/statics

volumes:
  static_volume:
```

This is inside my nginx container:

[image]

Also this is in my https config for my nginx:

[image]

Well to me it seems like everything is working and I can't understand what's wrong with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I checked the console of the browser and I found some warnings. The styles were fetched as text and the problem was the wrong `Content-Type` header. I add mime.types file to my container and include that in my nginx config.

`include /etc/nginx/mime.types;`

Comment: The issue was partly solved with this solution but still, I receive `Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)` error